# SSH Connection in ssh connection with c#

Tags: c#, ssh

I wrote an application for my own business.I connect to the servers using ssh connection. But i got a keyboard-interactive error while connecting to SOLARIS servers.I found a way to do this.I am doing ssh from linux server to solaris server.
this works manually but I can not get a response when doing this in c#.

```
if (txtSunucuismi.Text != "")
        {
            using (client = new SshClient("hostname1", 22, LDAP.username, LDAP.pass))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
                    client.Connect();
                    ss = client.CreateShellStream("msoffline",80,60,800,600,65536);

                    SshCommand sc1 = client.CreateCommand("ssh " + LDAP.username + "@hostname2");
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc1.CommandText);
                    sc1.Execute();
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc1.Result);
                    SshCommand sc2 = client.CreateCommand(LDAP.pass);
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc2.CommandText);
                    sc2.Execute();
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc2.Result);
                    SshCommand sc3 = client.CreateCommand("bash");
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc3.CommandText);
                    sc3.Execute();
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc3.Result);
                    SshCommand sc4 = client.CreateCommand("grep " + txtSunucuismi.Text + " /etc/hosts");
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc4.CommandText);
                    sc4.Execute();
                    listboxsonuc.Items.Add(sc4.Result);
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Hata :"+ex.Message);
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what's happening?

Comment: sc1.execute() 
then the program is not progressing. I wait for 60 seconds but there is no answer.

Comment: but uptime,ls /,echo hi commands are work ping "hostname" or ssh username@hostname doesn't work